# The latest version of translations

Tags: ppa, language-support, translation

***How can I get the latest versions of translations for Ubuntu?***

In Launchpad I can see that there are many improvements for translations in my language, some of them were made even a year ago (Uzbek language). But they don't appear in my computer yet and they are not coming with updates, although I update my system regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [this message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-translators/2015-March/006810.html), which I wrote yesterday on the ubuntu-translators mailing list, applies to your question as well. You'd better give us a couple of specific examples, and we may be able to check out if something is wrong.

Comment: For example, here https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/indicator-keyboard/+pots/indicator-keyboard/uz/+translate I see it is already translated, but in my keyboard indicator is showing Russian version (because I've appointed Russian as a second language)   Also here https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/indicator-datetime/+pots/indicator-datetime/uz/+translate?memo=10&start=10 Time and Date settings is translated but in my comp. it shows russian version.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Muzaffar: Most of those strings were reviewed in September 2014. Ubuntu 14.04 was released in April 2014, and unfortunately the [Uzbek Translators team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-uz) did not take the opportunity to participate in the coordinated translation updates of 14.04. In Ubuntu 14.10 those strings are displayed in Uzbek. If you want, you can request an update by [filing a bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/LanguagePackUpdateRequest).